# Lower bound for the order of an element modulo a prime power

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Let $x,d > 1$ be two coprime natural numbers and denote $|x|_k$ the multiplicative order of $x$ modulo $d^k$. Is it true that exists a constant $C > 0$ (depending on $x$ and $d$) such that $|x|_k \geq C d^k$?

Comments:

1. The upper bound has also this form an it is in fact independend of $x$. Indeed, $|x|_k \mid \phi(d^k) = (\phi(d)/d) d^k$ where $\phi$ is Euler's totient function.
2. There is a trivial lower bound that is $C \log(d^k)$. When $k$ is large enough, since $x$ is different to $1$, the smallest order would be $x^r = 1 + d^k$. This implies that $|x|_k > (1/log(x)) log(d^k)$.

Should you know any reference that works on a similar problem or any partial result to start looking at, that would be useful as well.

Comment: Yes. Use $(1+a p^l)^{p^r}\equiv 1+a p^{l+r}\bmod p^{l+r+1}$ if $p$ is prime and $l\ge 1$ if $p$ is odd, $l\ge 2$ is $p=2$. This will tell you the order of $x\bmod d^k$ from $k$ and the $p|d$-adic valuations of $x^o-1$ where $o$ is the order of $x\bmod d^2$.

Comment: Thanks! This helped to solve the prime case, but I feel there is still a problem in the general case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combining ideas with a friend we solved the problem, so I post it here in case someone else has the same question in the future:

**Lemma 1.** If $k \geq 2$, $(1 + ld^k)^r \equiv 1 + lrd^k \pmod{d^{k+2}}$

Proof: Applying binomial theorem, $(1 + ld^k)^r = \sum_{i = 0}^l \binom{l}{i} l^id^{ki}$. Since $k \geq 2$, for $i \geq 2$, $ki \geq 2k \geq k+2$ so $$(1 + ad^k)^l \equiv 1 + \binom{l}{1} ld^k \pmod{d^{k+2}}.$$

Let $t_k$ denote the multiplicative order of $x$ modulo $d^k$. Then, there exists $a_k$ such that $x^{t_k} = 1 + a_kd^k$.

**Lemma 2.** Fix $k$ and let $D = \gcd(d,a_k)$, $d = Dd'$ and $a_k = Da_k'$. Then $t_{k+1} = t_k d'$ and $a_{k+1} \equiv a_k' \pmod{d}$.

Proof: Applying Lemma 1, $(1+a_kd^k)^r \equiv 1 + lrd^k \pmod{d^{k+2}}$, and this is $1 \pmod{d^k}$ if and only if there exists $b$ integer such that $a_kr = bd$. Taking the common factor $D$ out, it is $1 \pmod{d^3}$ if and only if $a_k'r = bd'$. Since $(a_k',d') = 1$, this happens if and only if $d' \mid r$. Also, the equality happens if $r = d'$, so $t_{k+1} = d' t_k$ and $(1 + a_kd^k)^{d'} \equiv 1 + a_kd'd^{k} \pmod{d^{k+2}} \equiv 1 + a_k'd^{k+1} \pmod{d^{k+2}}$.

Notice that eventually $\gcd(d,a_k)$ will be $1$ because we are taking out the common factors every time. So by Lemma 2, eventually $t_{k+1} = dt_k$, proving the result.